# BYOL with oracle RDS

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds

I'm have created the oracle RDS with Bring your own license, But not getting anything? where i can add my existing oracle DB licence to oracle RDS.

I have tried with SQL developer there is no any option for this.

So, Is there any other  way to ad the license to Oracle RDS?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't use software keys. It is only "right to use" (RTU) the software.